# Web server Delphi can't create client

Tags: delphi, web, client

I have a web server in Delphi with the following function.

```
function Twebserver.Login(AUserName, APassword: string) : Tcustomer;
```

and in my client

```
var
  c := getISimpleCalculator.Login(AUserName, APassword);

  if c.custLogged = '1' then
  begin
  showmessage('olaaa11');
  end
   else
 begin
  messagedlg('Usuario ou senha incorreta', mterror, [mbok], 0);
   end;
```

and I got this error when I'm trying to log in:

> raised exception class `ERemotableException`
>   access violation at address....

Why can't I log in? I'm passing the user and password in tedit 1 and tedit2.

Answer (score 0):

A ERemotebleException has been thrown on the server side of the web service. There is not much you can do on the client side if the input values of the remote method call are correct. I suggest debugging the server code using the parameters passed to the Login method.

Comment: huum, ok so may be i have wrong values ... i can use this ?                       function Twebserver.Login(AUserName, APassword: string) : Tcustomer;        Tcustomer = class(Tremotable)
    private
      FcustUserName : String;
      FcustCode : String;
  tPendingOrders;
  end;...........